# Page load cancel event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I display a metro style loader while page is loading, then hide it when page loaded with `$('#page-loader').fadeOut();`

Again show it on `onbeforeunload` event when user click any links or submit any forms. in this case user may cancel leaving page with `Esc`, now how can I hide loader again?

```
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#page-loader').fadeOut();
    });
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        $('#page-loader').fadeIn();
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 27){
            $('#page-loader').fadeOut();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What about browser's cancel button?

Comment: try listening `document.onstop`